# ExactTarget Segmenting Email Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud

Want to see if anyone else has run into this and how they possibly have handled. For sends that you want to send customized content to different subscribers based on data extensions/ampscript essentially is one main send content template and then segmented into many different send types based on the data from the data extension.

In the tracking area the sends all under the one default content name. How can this easily be filterable to see tracking of each send but be able to differentiate sends as each send has the same name although they are going to different groups?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done something similar.

1. Do all my segmenting with Query Activities and/or Filter Activities, and store the results  in corresponding data extensions.
2. Set up a User Initiated Send (Activity) to send an email (in this case the same base email that renders dymamically at send time).  The recipients of this send would be on one of the data extensions I set up in step#1.  I would set up a UISend for each of the DE's I set up in step1.
3. Link step1&2 in an automation.
4. You then view all the tracking results separately, as they are part of different UIsends.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what we are doing now. One main content email (message) and several user-initiated emails. But in the tracking tab it shows as the "name" the main content email name not the user-initiated name so they are all named the same (which is not helpful). So how do I get the tracking name to be more personalized so I can tell which are which?

Comment: The name is the name of the email object, not the send (UIS name). The process above is good for Master List/DE > Segmentation into Child List/DE > Unique Email/UIS for each Child List/DE.

Comment: I appreciate the correction.  And it had been a while, so I'm rusty.  So, next thought: what if you put the entire contents of the email in a content area?  Then, create an HTML email (containing 1 line to load the content area) to calcorresponding to each UI send?  A pain initially to be sure, but at least this way, if you wanted to change the underlying content, you would only have to do it in one place.